# How to choose what argument a variable is assigned to in a function? -Javascript

Tags: javascript

Given a normal function as such;

```
function descriptions(awesome, cool, alright){
   return (awesome || "no one") + " is awesome. " + cool + " is cool. " +
     + alright + " is alright";
}
descriptions("jane", "jack", "jefferson");
//returns "jane is awesome. jack is cool. jefferson is alright."
```

I would like to use the same function, but would only like to pass it the final two arguments like so:

```
descriptions(cool : "john", alright : "jane"); //I would like a statement similar to this that works.
//should return "no one is awesome. jack is cool. jefferson is alright."
```

How would the above be done?

Comment: You cannot. JS does not support named parameters.

Comment: Should I remove my question?

Comment: Let's see what community thinks. It's a valid question and "No" is a perfect answer.

Comment: You can achieve the same result by using a different data structure and control flow. Are you interested?

Comment: Definitely interested.

Comment: Pass a single object instead

Comment: `function descriptions({ awesome = 'no one', cool, alright })`

Comment: @zerkms What about the return statement?

Comment: You mean `descriptions({awesome:"jane", cool:"jack", alright:"jefferson"});`

Comment: @JasonBasanese what about it?

Comment: @ zerkmsI misunderstood you comment. No worries.

Comment: @JasonBasanese added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by passing an object:

```
function descriptions(info) {
    // Avoid TypeError if no argument is passed
    if (!info) {
        info = {};
    }

    return (info.awesome || "no one") + " is awesome. " + (info.cool || "no one") + " is cool. " + (info.alright || "no one") + " is alright.";
}

// Use:
console.log(descriptions({
    awesome: "Strong Bad",
    cool: "The Cheat",
    alright: "Strong Sad"
}));
```

Comment: Chosen for simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

Something different syntactically but similar semantically might be achieved using object destructuring

```
function descriptions({ awesome = 'no one', cool, alright }) {
    return awesome + " is awesome. " + cool + " is cool. " +
     + alright + " is alright";
}
```

Then you just invoke it with an object with corresponding properties:

```
descriptions({ cool: 'a', alright: 'b'});
```

Comment: You know, having been away from JS for much of the past two years, some of this new-fangled ES6 stuff is beginning to look like deep magicks.

Comment: Would the above function work if passed { awesome : "someone" }? Setting awesome to "someone".

Comment: @JasonBasanese what about the other properties? In the current implementation the others don't have default values.

Comment: Also evaluating that function threw the following error-> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: @zerkms I guess I am somewhat confused on what your function is doing. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @JasonBasanese https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=true&playground=true&code=function%20descriptions(%7B%20awesome%20%3D%20'no%20one'%2C%20cool%2C%20alright%20%7D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20awesome%20%2B%20%22%20is%20awesome.%20%22%20%2B%20cool%20%2B%20%22%20is%20cool.%20%22%20%2B%20alright%20%2B%20%22%20is%20alright%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(descriptions(%7B%20cool%3A%20'a'%2C%20alright%3A%20'b'%7D))%3B + https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible in any variety of ECMAScript (including JavaScript).

It is theoretically possible to do things like use conditional, custom logic:

```
function(a,b,c){
   if(arguments.length === 1) {
      // we're in object mode;
      b = a.b
      c = a.c
      a = a.a || 'default';
   }
}
```

But that is not a built in part of the language.

This is *NOT* possible, for example:

```
function foo(a,b,c){return a/(b || 1) + c;}
foo({c:1,b:2,a:3})
```

There is also the possibility to conditionally define values based on number of arguments:

```
function say (a,b,c) {
   if(arguments.length === 2) {
      c = b;
      b = a;
      a = 'cat';
   }
   console.log('a ' + a + ' likes a ' + b + ' and a ' + c)
}
say('dog', 'bone', 'walk') // a dog likes a bone and a walk
say('mouse', 'bowl of milk') // a cat likes a mouse and a bowl of milk
```

Comment: Is there a workaround? Maybe something involving objects?

Comment: Is this assuming a is an object passed to the function?

Comment: The first example assumes that the first argument (`a`) is an object passed to the function. The function must be written to anticipate that parameter, however.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can certainly achieve this!
You can use a clever trick many developers use to set a variable to a default value if one is not provided.

```
function descriptions(awesome, cool, alright){
awesome = awesome || "";
if (awesome === "")
{
    return "no one" + " is awesome. " + cool + " is cool. " +
 + alright + " is alright";
}
else{
    return awesome + " is awesome. " + cool + " is cool. " +
 + alright + " is alright";
}

}
console.log(descriptions(undefined, "jack", "jefferson"));
```

Here is the working code. You could also pass an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

In ECMAScript 6, this can sort of be done if you change your parameters to receive an object and take advantage of [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```js
function descriptions({awesome: awesome = "no one", cool: cool = "", alright: alright = ""} = {}) {
     return awesome + " is awesome. " + 
            cool + " is cool. " +
            alright + " is alright";
}


var res = descriptions({ cool: "john", alright: "jane" });


document.body.textContent = res;
```

So we have someone of an emulation of named parameters. Only thing extra needed by the caller is the curly braces.

Of course browser support is limited, but transpilers are available.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a different approach:

```
var coolLevels = {
  isCool: ["Jack", "John"]
, isAlright: ["Jane", "Jefferson"]
, isAwesome: []
}

function describe(people, coolLevel, phrase) {
  return people.filter(function(person){
    return Boolean(coolLevel.indexOf(person))
  }).join(", ") + phrase
}

function descriptions(people){
  var awesome = describe(people, coolLevels.isAwesome, ' is awesome.')
  var cool = describe(people, coolLevels.isCool, ' is cool.')
  var alright = describe(people, coolLevels.isCool, ' is alright.')

  return awesome + cool + alright
}
```

demo: https://jsbin.com/kahawuhelu/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `undefined`, `null` or `""` as the first parameter. E.g:

```
descriptions(null, "jack", "jefferson");
```

Since you already use `awesome || "no one"`, any falsy value will be good enough.

---

Another approach would be changing the function to receive an object:

```
function descriptions(options) {
  return (options.awesome || "no one") + " is awesome. " + options.cool + " is cool. " + 
    options.alright + " is alright";
}

descriptions({ cool: "jack", alright: "jefferson" });
```

---

Now, depending on your browser support, you can use ES6 destructuring parameters:

```
const descriptions = ({ awesome = 'no one', cool, alright }) => (
  `${awesome} is awesome. ${cool} is cool. ${alright} is alright`
);

descriptions({ cool: 'jack', alright: 'jefferson' });
```